# How to make sub-syntaxes? Seems a syntax "category" is required

Tags: syntax, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

My goal is to extend the `text.html` syntax with a `text.html.django` syntax, so (for example) Django-only autocompletes don't show up when I'm working on a non-Django html file. Same thing with `source.python` and `source.python.django`.

The [Djaniero package](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Djaneiro) does just this, and using [PackageResourceViewer](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer), I've copied both syntax files and saved them into my User directory (both are below).

It's not working, and I'm wondering if it's because, when Djaniero in installed, these syntaxes are listed in a category:

[image: screenshot]

But when I uninstall Djaniero, my syntaxes are not showing up in that same list. I am not finding anything obvious in the Djaniero resource files on how to make this category.

How do I create this syntax category? Or if that's not the issue, what am I missing?

Thanks.

---

`C:\Users\jeffy\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\syntax_definitions\Python Django.tmLanguage`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>fileTypes</key>
   <array>
      <string>py</string>
   </array>
   <key>foldingStartMarker</key>
   <string>^\s*(def|class)\s+([.a-zA-Z0-9_ b]+)\s*(\((.*)\))?\s*:|\{\s*$|\(\s*$|\[\s*$</string>
   <key>foldingStopMarker</key>
   <string>^\s*$|^\s*\}|^\s*\]|^\s*\)</string>
   <key>keyEquivalent</key>
   <string>^~P</string>
   <key>name</key>
   <string>Python Django</string>
   <key>patterns</key>
   <array>
      <dict>
         <key>match</key>
         <string>(meta|models)\.(Admin|AutoField|BigIntegerField|BooleanField|CharField|CommaSeparatedIntegerField|DateField|DateTimeField|DecimalField|EmailField|FileField|FilePathField|FloatField|ForeignKey|ImageField|IntegerField|IPAddressField|ManyToManyField|NullBooleanField|OneToOneField|PhoneNumberField|PositiveIntegerField|PositiveSmallIntegerField|SlugField|SmallIntegerField|TextField|TimeField|URLField|USStateField|XMLField)\b</string>
         <key>name</key>
         <string>support.type.django.model</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
         <key>match</key>
         <string>django(\.[a-z]+){1,} </string>
         <key>name</key>
         <string>support.other.django.module</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
         <key>match</key>
         <string>(ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES|ADMIN_FOR|ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX|ADMINS|ALLOWED_HOSTS|ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS|APPEND_SLASH|AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS|AUTH_USER_MODEL|AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE|CACHE_BACKEND|CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS|CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY|CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX|CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS|CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN|CSRF_COOKIE_NAME|CSRF_COOKIE_PATH|CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE|CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW|DATABASES|DATABASE_ENGINE|DATABASE_HOST|DATABASE_NAME|DATABASE_OPTIONS|DATABASE_PASSWORD|DATABASE_PORT|DATABASE_USER|DATABASE_ROUTERS|DATE_FORMAT|DATE_INPUT_FORMATS|DATETIME_FORMAT|DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS|DEBUG|DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS|DECIMAL_SEPARATOR|DEFAULT_CHARSET|DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE|DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER|DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE|DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL|DEFAULT_TABLESPACE|DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE|DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS|EMAIL_BACKEND|EMAIL_FILE_PATH|EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD|EMAIL_HOST_USER|EMAIL_HOST|EMAIL_PORT|EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX|EMAIL_USE_TLS|FILE_CHARSET|FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS|FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE|FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS|FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR|FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK|FIXTURE_DIRS|FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME|FORMAT_MODULE_PATH|IGNORABLE_404_ENDS|IGNORABLE_404_STARTS|IGNORABLE_404_URLS|INSTALLED_APPS|INTERNAL_IPS|JING_PATH|LANGUAGE_CODE|LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME|LANGUAGES|LOCALE_PATHS|LOGGING|LOGGING_CONFIG|LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL|LOGIN_URL|LOGOUT_URL|MANAGERS|MEDIA_ROOT|MEDIA_URL|MESSAGE_LEVEL|MESSAGE_STORAGE|MESSAGE_TAGS|MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES|MONTH_DAY_FORMAT|NUMBER_GROUPING|PASSWORD_HASHERS|PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS|PREPEND_WWW|PROFANITIES_LIST|RESTRUCTUREDTEXT_FILTER_SETTINGS|ROOT_URLCONF|SECRET_KEY|SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER|SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS|SERIALIZATION_MODULES|SERVER_EMAIL|SESSION_ENGINE|SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS|SESSION_COOKIE_AGE|SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN|SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY|SESSION_COOKIE_NAME|SESSION_COOKIE_PATH|SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE|SESSION_ENGINE|SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE|SESSION_FILE_PATH|SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST|SHORT_DATE_FORMAT|SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT|SIGNING_BACKEND|SITE_ID|STATIC_ROOT|STATIC_URL|STATICFILES_DIRS|STATICFILES_FINDERS|STATICFILES_STORAGE|TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS|TEMPLATE_DEBUG|TEMPLATE_DIRS|TEMPLATE_LOADERS|TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID|TEST_DATABASE_CHARSET|TEST_DATABASE_COLLATION|TEST_DATABASE_NAME|TEST_RUNNER|THOUSAND_SEPARATOR|TIME_FORMAT|TIME_INPUT_FORMATS|TIME_ZONE|TRANSACTIONS_MANAGED|URL_VALIDATOR_USER_AGENT|USE_ETAGS|USE_I18N|USE_L10N|USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR|USE_TZ|USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST|WSGI_APPLICATION|YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT|X_FRAME_OPTIONS)\b</string>
         <key>name</key>
         <string>variable.other.django.settings</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
         <key>match</key>
         <string>(get_list_or_404|get_object_or_404|load_and_render|loader|render_to_response|render)\b</string>
         <key>name</key>
         <string>support.function.django.view</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
         <key>match</key>
         <string>[a-z_]+\.get_(object|list|iterator|count|values|values_iterator|in_bulk)\b</string>
         <key>name</key>
         <string>support.function.django.model</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
         <key>include</key>
         <string>source.python</string>
      </dict>
   </array>
   <key>scopeName</key>
   <string>source.python.django</string>
   <key>uuid</key>
   <string>5326D56C-6F76-4758-8DB7-D818527919AC</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

`C:\Users\jeffy\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\syntax_definitions\HTML (Django).tmLanguage`

*This file is enormous. Here it is as [a dpaste](http://dpaste.com/0DWRWA0).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out a "User" category was automatically created. I just didn't notice it.

[image: screenshot]